# How to test more than 2 components using VeeValidate?

Tags: vue.js, vue-test-utils, vee-validate

When I try to test 2 components (with 2 different test files), just the first file will pass.

The second will fail with `[Vue warn]: Error in directive validate bind hook: "TypeError: Cannot read property '$scopedSlots' of undefined"`.

I'm really failing to get this working. Has anyone seen/solved this problem?

Already placed issues at [`VeeValidate`](https://github.com/baianat/vee-validate/issues/1996) and [`vue-test-utils`](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-test-utils/issues/1205).

You can reproduce this behavior here: https://github.com/jourdanrodrigues/v-validate-issue

Just clone, install and `npm run test:unit`. You'll see the error.

Comment: For future reference, I decided to remove VeeValidate from my project and use plain HTML5.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add `sync: false` to the mount/shallowMount options.
see https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/api/options.html#sync